# CSRF Protection without using template Engine- Javascript and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, csrf

I have a single page webapp that I am writing that will take a user name and api key and will do REST full API calls. Since the user uses a apikey for their account, there is no need to log in. I am not using cookies ether.

On the backend, I am using a simple flask server. The front end is a custom written without a framework using mostly html and vanilla JavaScript. I am not sure how to implement CSRF protection without using a framework. I could use Javascript to dynamically generate a token and place it in the html form field as a hidden element. But I don't know how I would get that token to the flask server so it could have it to compare. Without using a template engine, how could I do this?

Comment: Since it uses API-key, I am not sure why you would require CSRF Protection.

Comment: I was under the impression that the html form could be exploited and the information could be redirected(such api key). Is this possible without a CSRF token in my situation?

Comment: But you shouldn't be setting the API key in the form field.

Comment: ah...I think I see. Should I grab the element that has the API key value with JS, manually serialize it and send it in the post?

Comment: It is too broad to be answered in Q&A format, but I can give you few hints. Generate CSRF tokens in the server side and send them out along with the HTML form you generate, also you need to store the token somewhere in the server. When the request comes back to you, check token is present and it is valid. If they are not, send the error page otherwise use the API Key and submit the request yourself in the server.

Comment: This goes back to the original question...the html is form is not generated because I am not using a template system. It's a static page.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to generate csrf token from server and client can get it through a simple request, then pass it back in post request. You can use below method to generate token.

```
flask_wtf.csrf.generate_csrf(secret_key=None, time_limit=None)
```

For example,

```
@app.route('/token')

def token():

    token=generate_csrf(time_limit=10)

    return jsonify({'token':token}), 201
```

Then post request with header `'X-CSRFToken'`

Comment: How does that protect your app from cross site request forgery?
Before doing a malicious request, someone could hit your /token route before, get the token and inject it into his own request. What is the benefit of generating it like that?

Comment: @bRo Do you mean the attacker could visit the token route in their own browser? Yes, but they will get their own token which will not match the victim's, so the cross site request will be rejected. If you mean they could make a cross site request to the token endpoint, yes, but same-origin policy means they can't read the token. It's no different to having the token as a hidden input on a form - the attacker could visit the form page in their own browser and get a token but it won't match the victim's. The attacker could make a cross site request to the form page but can't read the token.